# Multiple audio/video streams in HTML5

Tags: html, audio, video, stream

I need to develop an HTML5 based app which can handle multiple audio/video streams from a single machine. For instance, I attach 2 webcams and one mic to the system. I need the system to give option to me which one to use from the 3 and select/publish multiple streams at same time.